# Used require, stdin not being highlighted or working

Tags: ruby, string, events

What I've been trying to do is a simple noob project just by trying to take in
minor keys. Don't know if this is a ruby version or aptana weirdness because "STDIN.getch" and "raise" are not highlighted as if they are important or work at all. The code runs but nothing happens. the else does not fire either.

```
require 'io/console'

def yesno
  case STDIN.getch
  when "Y" then true
  when "N" then false
  else raise "Invalid character."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining a method `yesno` but never invoking it.

Just write

```
yesno
```

after the final `end`